# How can I find port running Oracle Enterprise Manager

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-enterprise-manager

I need to connect to the Oracle Enterprise manager of a remote machine. But I dont know the port on which OEM is running on the remote machine. I have access to the machine from terminal though.

Is there a command to see the port number OEM is running on. The remote machine is CentOS and I need to open the OEM on my local browser (I am running windows 10)

I would really appreciate all the help. I am new to Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

`emctl status dbconsole` displays the URL and port where you can access EM.

Comment: I tried this command but it says emctl command not found. But I am sure that Oracle is installed on that machine.

Comment: navigate to the $ORACLE_HOME\bin folder, you can run emctl from there

Answer (score 0):

The port configuration is documented in the following file:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/install/portlist.ini
```

If Enterprise Manager has been installed then setting off the following command will show the status of the Enterprise Manager:

```
./emctl status dbconsole
```

If you are receiving the following message:

> ```
> ./emctl:  not found.
> ```

...then you might not have Enterprise Management Console installed.

The Management Console is not required to have a fully functional Oracle RDBMS instance up and running.

Comment: emctl might not be in the path

Comment: @AndrewBrennan even if it is in the path this may not work because `./emctl` requeires emctl in the current directory